# Selecting only one button from button-group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a button group, where button from a group can be selected at once.

Let's suppose we have got three buttons, the user should be able to select only one button, so if user selects "Apple" then they shouldn't be able to select the Apple button again.

The main purpose will be to stop user selecting the button which is already selected.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `<button type="button">` isn't a correct way to use button. You can use `<input type="button">` or simply `<button></button>`

Comment: So, whats a problem find the follow code in bootstrap, and understand how it work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This seems to be exactly what are you searching for.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Apple
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Samsung
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Sony
  </label>
</div>
```

You can read more about this [under this link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio). This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You should use radiobuttons in this way.

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #999;
 background-color: #eee;
}

form {
 margin: 40px 0;
}

div {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

label {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4
}

input.radio:empty {
 margin-left: -999px;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 line-height: 2.5em;
 text-indent: 3.25em;
 margin-top: 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

input.radio:empty ~ label:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 2.5em;
 background: #D1D3D4;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #C2C2C2;
}

input.radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
 color: #888;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\2714';
 text-indent: .9em;
 color: #9CE2AE;
 background-color: #4DCB6D;
}

input.radio:checked ~ label {
 color: #777;
}

input.radio:focus ~ label:before {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
<label for="radio1">Apple</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio2">Samsung</label>
</div>

<div> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
<label for="radio3">Sony</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need button not checkbox, input type="radio" will make it as a check box

Comment: @ChristoferHansen so I can't understand what a problem:( It's not possible without js, I think

Answer (score 4):

For Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

[See the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

`Button` are used for buttons

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apple" name="radio"> Apple
          <input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" value= "Samsung" name="radio"> Samsung
          <input type="radio" class="btn btn-primary" value "Sony" name="radio"> Sony
</div>
```

Radios are `<input type="radio">`. If you want only one radio checked they have to get the same  `name`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need button not checkbox, input type="radio" will make it as a check box ...

Comment: I don't understand. What is the server supposed to do when a button is clicked because you can't click many buttons at once. If you click one button others wont be clicked. I think that what you want is radio buttons